# Writing power series as function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to write the following power series as a function:

$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n+1}$

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Hint: use a geometric series.

Comment: What do you mean "write it as a function"? It's already a function with domain $|x|<1. $ I guess what you mean is "find a simple formula for this function."

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

The sum can be written as 
$$
2x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^{n}
$$
and recall the formula for a geometric series.